# In order for spherical mirror to focus, why do we need $\mu > h_1$?

Tags: optics, reflection, geometric-optics, geometry

[image]

We know that in order for a spherical mirror to focus, the equation $$y^2 = 4fx - x^2$$ do behave like the parabola equation $$y^2 = 4fx,$$ so we need $$f>> x.$$

However, it is told me that the inequality $u > h_1$, and similarly $v>h_2$ should also hold, but why is that so ?

Answer (score 1):

A parabolic mirror will focus rays which are parallel to the principal axis to a point but will not do this if the rays are not parallel to the principal axis even if the rays are parallel to one another.

The further the rays are inclined to the principal axis the greater is the aberration which is primarily [coma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coma_(optics)).
So keeping the image and object sizes small compared with the image and object distances small will reduce the inclination of some of the rays to the principal axis and so reduced aberration.

[image]

[There is more about this at this website](http://www.faculty.virginia.edu/rwoclass/astr511/lec16-teloptics-f03.html)

Comment: But how can we show this mathematically ?

Comment: I mean basically what I'm trying to show that $f >> x$ implies $\mu >> h_1$.

Comment: There is an analysis here. http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu//full/1898ApJ.....7..114P/0000114.000.html

Comment: Article is hardly opening, is there any way that I can access the same article  from a different source ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas I googled “charles lane poor aberration parabolic mirror” and it was the first link in the list. Then use “next article page” to get to the next page.

Comment: By the way, this analysis is for a point object, which does not have any height obviously.

Comment: @onurcanbektas Does the point at the top of your object translate into a point image?